# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to set the maximum value on any pixel to be 255, in any color channel. My image is RGB16, if the pixel's colors are greater than 255, then the value should be changed by 255.

I tried to do this with thresholding:

```
cvf = cv2.threshold(cvf, 255, 255, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
```

But then, attempting to convert that to uint8:

```
cvf = np.uint8(cvf)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.

Comment: just use numpy. `cvf[cvf > 255] = 255` and then `... cvf.astype(np.uint8) ...`

Comment: The solution is simple... use: `ret, cvf = cv2.threshold(cvf, 255, 255, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)`